# Adding evenlistener to header of div

Tags: css, html, drag-and-drop

I have multiple eventlisteners to my div: `dragstart`, `dragenter`, `dragover`, `dragleave`, `drop` and `dragend`.

To attach them to my div, I use the `body onload` function:

```
function addListeners()
{
    var cols = document.querySelectorAll('#columns .column');
    [].forEach.call(cols, function(col) {
      col.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
      col.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
      col.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
      col.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
      col.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
      col.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
    });
}
```

**but** this code adds the eventlistener to the whole div. I only want the header of the div to respond to these events:

[image: drag and drop example]

Now I can click on any part of the div and drag it, but I only want to be able to click on the black part (header) of the div to move it. The black part is a simple `header` in CSS.

#### HTML

```
<body onload="addListeners()">

<div id="columns">
  <div class="column" draggable="true"><header>A</header>Textual information inside div A</div>
  <div class="column" draggable="true"><header>B</header>Textual information inside div B</div>
  <div class="column" draggable="true"><header>C</header>Textual information inside div C</div>
</div>

</body>
```

A JSFiddle of my full page can be found [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxcpr/)

How can this be done?

Comment: Can you add the HTML code?

Comment: @Babblo Has been added.

Comment: but you are adding the events to the entire div.column? try adding it only to the <header>

Comment: @ManishMishra Yes, that's what I'm asking, how to add it only to the header ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add EventListeners to your `header` elements.

but those `event listeners` will work only when your headers are `draggable=true`

so by adding EventListeners to the header and making it `draggable=true` you can start to drag it.

But there is one problem now, you don't want to drag just the header, but its entire content i.e its parent div. and you want to swap it with the  `parentNode.innerHTML` of the other header(upon which you are dropping).

so, you need to do this:

- add events to the header element,
- perform all the other operation i.e. grabbing and then swapping innerHTML on the parent of the header i.e. `this.parentNode`
- also when you perform the innerHTML swap, all the event listeners are lost,because now, the very draggable element is recreated, so you will have to call your event binding function `addListeners()` again.

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmishra256/mFpWF/1/)